# Jersey 2 Multipart upload Client

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I want to write a simple jersey 2 client to upload a file. I'm using Jersey 2.10.1 and wrote following server code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream aUploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition aFileDetail) {

    UploadedFile uploadedFile = new UploadedFile();
    uploadedFile.setOriginalFileName(aFileDetail.getFileName());
    uploadedFile.setFileSize(aFileDetail.getSize());
    saveToFile(aUploadedInputStream, aFileDetail.getType(), uploadedFile);
    databaseHelper.saveInDatabase(uploadedFile);

    return Response.status(200).build();
}
```

("UploadedFile" is an custom class to save the information of the file in a database)

And this is my client code:

```
private static final String TARGET_URL = "http://localhost:49158/rest/service/upload";

public Slimclient() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(TARGET_URL);
    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();

    FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file",
            new File("C:/Users/Nicklas2751/Desktop/test.txt"), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    multiPart.bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);

    Response response = webTarget.request(
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(
            Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));

    System.out.println(response.getStatus()+" "+response.getStatusInfo()+" "+response);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Slimclient();
}
```

The server code runs without any problems but when i run the client i get the following error:

```
415 Unsupported Media Type InboundJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://localhost:49158/rest/service/upload, status=415, reason=Unsupported Media Type}}
```

I searched the web for a good tutorial for jersey 2 and multipart fileupload but i can only find tutorials and examples for jersey 1 or with an HTML-Form as "Client". I hope sombody can help me :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I've found my problem. I've missed to set the `MediaType` of the `MultiPart` and with the `.request(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)` I've set the expected `MediaType` of the response to `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`. Here is the working code:

```
public class Slimclient {
    private static final String TARGET_URL = "http://localhost:49158/rest/service/upload";

    public Slimclient() {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(TARGET_URL);
        MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
        multiPart.setMediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

        FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file",
            new File("C:/Users/Nicklas/Desktop/aab.txt"),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
        multiPart.bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);

        Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));

        System.out.println(response.getStatus() + " "
            + response.getStatusInfo() + " " + response);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Slimclient();
    }
}
```

Comment: I try your solution and I get an argument type mismatch exception on server.  Did you also make a change to server?

Comment: Found the problem, we had to do this on our server:          resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);

Comment: Why is your request taking JSON type? Shouldn't it be Multipart_form?

Comment: Because i send Multipart_form and the Server is responding with JSON data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It helped me solve a similar problem after much frustration.  There is also a `StreamDataBodyPart` that will work in place of the `FileDataBodyPart` shown above, if your data is an `InputStream` instead of a `File`.

Comment: Which packages do you use? I can't find MultiPart.

Comment: jersy-media-multipart-2.0.jar

Answer (score 1):

Because your server side consumes `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`, your client code could use `FormDataMultiPart` directly instead of `MultiPart`.

```
FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
```